# Is there a way to draw a diagram that represents the relationship of variables in formula/conditional statement?

Tags: python, tree, spss, diagram, dataflow

I have an algorithm like this :

```
A = 0 if B == 1 or C == 1 else A = 1
D = A + E
F = D/2
```

I'd like to represent relationships between variables as a dataflow or a tree diagram. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaniO.jpg)

I have a bunch of such formula which are to be updated regularly, so would like to find a way to do this programmatically rather than drawing manually. Is there any such library in Python or SPSS to do so?

Comment: Even in pseudo code you should avoid mixing up *assignment* and *equality comparison*. How does the first assignment work when `B == 2`?

Comment: Answer for SPSS: nope.

Comment: ...ok, but there was a question there.

Comment: @trincot I actually meant equality comparison for B and C and edited the code

Comment: Yes, that is about the first half of my first comment, but the second half asks this question: *"How does the first assignment work when `B == 2`?"*. Can you answer? In other words... what will the value of `A` be when `B == 2`?

Comment: right, sorry for missing that out - let me add 'else' part.

Answer (score 0):

Explore `networkx`. You have to install [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) package and [`graphviz`](https://graphviz.org/) program:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout

relations = [('B', 'A'), ('C', 'A'), ('A', 'D'), ('E', 'D'), ('D', 'F')]

# Create graph and add egdes
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(relations)

pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, arrows=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]